# responsive sizing images next.js with tailwind

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I have seen that there have been many changes with next.js image sizing over the past few versions. My current version is "next": "13.4.4". I am trying to make responsive image sizes so that a given image takes up 20% of the screen width and the height adjusts accordingly. With next.js version 13, many features are deprecated, like "layout".

Here is my current code:

```js
<div className="w-1/5 h-1/5 relative pt-[100%]">
            <Image
            src={user.user.photoURL}
            alt="profile image"
            fill 
            style={{ objectFit: "cover" }}
            />
</div>
```

This leaves me with an image that is the right width, but the height is the whole screen (minus header and footer). How should I fix it so that the height doesn't expand like that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to get rid of the "style" attribute and giving it an "object-cover" class? I could assume the style attribute is conflicting with tailwind

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the width and height (or aspect-ratio) of the image when using object-fit.

If you set the image height to be `h-full` (`height: 100%`) then you also need to be sure the height of the parent div (`h-1/5`) is effective. That would depend on the parent container, but not shown in your demo code.

If you want 20% of the screen height you could use `h-[20vh]` if that helps.

Some demo code to show different results. Only the first example gives the `object-cover` effect that you want:

```
<p class="mt-10">With image height</p>
<div class="w-1/5 aspect-square relative bg-slate-300">
    <img class="w-full h-full object-cover" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554629947-334ff61d85dc?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=640&amp;h=320&amp;q=80" />
  </div>
</div>

<p class="mt-10">Without image height</p>
<div class="w-1/5 aspect-square relative bg-slate-300">
    <img class="w-full object-cover" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554629947-334ff61d85dc?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=640&amp;h=320&amp;q=80" />
  </div>
</div>

<p class="mt-10">Without height on container</p>
<div class="w-1/5 relative bg-slate-300">
    <img class="w-full h-full object-cover" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1554629947-334ff61d85dc?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&amp;ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;w=640&amp;h=320&amp;q=80" />
  </div>
</div>
```

https://play.tailwindcss.com/XlquKIXny8

Comment: Ok, I did the first suggestion with image height, and that worked. Thank you!